# i can't get the response from the server how do i get the response from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios, http-post

Signup.jsx

```
        axiosClient.post("/signup", payload)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                setUser(data.user);
                setToken(data.token);
                console.log('data', data);
            }
            )
            .catch((err) => {
                const response = err.response;
                if (response && response.status === 422) {
                    setErrors(response.data.errors);
                }

            });
```

response from the server : ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4NTQ.png)

i was expecting the .then method to handle the response from the server. It expects the response. Inside the callback function, the`your text` `setUser` function is called with the value of `data.user`, which is the user object returned by the server. Similarly, the `setToken` function is called with the value of `data.token`, which is  an authentication token provided by the server
but the script skip the .then method to the rest of this code

**PS: when Im trying to log/print the data contained in the `data` variable it shows me that it is null**

Comment: what if, for troubleshooting purposes, you change `.then(({ data }) => { etc` to just `.then(console.log)` to inspect what `axiosClient.post` is giving you

Comment: .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })

Comment: @StewieSWS it is always undefined i have no idea why even if the db server returns the required data !!

Comment: hi, how can the response be undefined if you can see it in the image you posted? try ```.then((response)=> { console.log(response);console.log(response.user);console.log(response.user.name);})```